# How to install Tensorflow via conda for Python 3.10.*?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I am using miniconda, v4.13.0, I can install Tensorflow using `conda install tensorflow` to my conda environment if its Python version 3.9.*  However I would like to use Python 3.10.*

If the Python version is 3.10.* in my conda environment then command `conda install tensorflow` gives the specification incompatibility error:

- tensorflow -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|3.8.*|3.7.*|3.9.*']

**Question**

Is there any way to install Tensorflow via conda where the Python version is 3.10.*?

Comment: @I'mahdi, I do know that tensorflow supports Python 3.10.*, I am asking if is it possible to install it via conda install. It is also strange, that the latest conda install tensorflow installs tensorflow 2.6, when the latest is 2.9...

Comment: you need tensorflow > 2.8. try this : `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=2.8`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command to install `TensorFlow` using python 3.10:

```
conda create --name tf python=3.10
conda activate tf
conda install tensorflow
```

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) link for reference.

Comment: I really don't see a single line in this answer where you install tensroflow

Answer (score 0):

You can find here tensorflow github PR

https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/pull/2635